# Date column is blank when being filtered by a date column in another table

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have a calculated date table, and a fact table, linked by the date field in both tables both are date types:

[image]

The end goal is to be able to filter bi-directionally, and filter a visual by both dates.

I'm struggling to get the first slicer figured out.

I have two visuals: column with each of the date fields, and a slicer on the 'Date'[Date] field:

[image: table]

When I click on a date in the date visual, OR change the slicer values on the date table, all values in the safety stock visual are filtered out, even though there are valid values in the safety stock table. As you can see from the second picture, there ARE valid safety stock dates for  11/15/2012.

[image]

As far as I can understand, the relationship should make the filter work correctly.